# How to change axis labels of a plotly barplot

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

im trying to plot a waterfall plot where every single bar is a different subject, and its height is the value that i measuring. I would like to change x axis labels to have n values (0, 50, 100,... until n size) instead of every subject's ID. In this case I am using the package plotly because i need to animate the results through a time variable.

This is my code:

```
`fig <- df %>% plot_ly(
    x = ~ID, 
    y = ~Y, 
    color = ~Age, 
    hoverinfo = "text",
    frame = ~ Month,
    type = 'bar',
    marker = list(line = list(color = "black", width = 0.6)))`
```

I tried to use a numerical ID, but does not order it as i would like to (increasing y value). ID is character var, Y numerical, and Age and Month both character vars FYI.

EDIT: dput() output FYI

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c("ABC-001", 
                                     "ABC-001", "ABC-001", "ABC-001", 
                                     "ABC-002", "ABC-002", "ABC-002", 
                                     "ABC-003", "ABC-003", "ABC-004"), label = "Unique Subject Identifier"), 
                Month = c(-1, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16), 
               Y = structure(c(NA, NA, -37.254901961, -66.274509804, -78.823529412, -84.31372549, -89.411764706, 
                               -95.294117647, -97.647058824, -92.549019608), label = "Value"), 
               ARM = c("<= 18", "<= 18", "<= 18", "<= 18", "(18 , 64]", "(18 , 64]", "(18 , 64]", "> 64", "> 64", "> 64")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), label = "Analysis Dataset", class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Done! Let me know if you need something else

Comment: What is your expected outcome? I am not completely sure what you mean n values (0, 50, 100). Can't you simply change the ID with these values as a character?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt explain myself enough. I had a large number of ID (n = 450), and my expected outcome is, instead of having ID labels on the x axis, i want to have labels that indicate how many subjects are until that point (tick at 50, 100,..., 450), so then, i will know how many people are above a certain y value. BTW i found a "solution" that ill upload later, that is selecting the ID's in those positions tickvals = c(0, 50,...,450) and renaming manually the label ticklabel = c("0","50",...). Doing this seems to work atm, and the results make sense. Thank you Quinten for your help!